# Windows store app crashes not get logged in Application Insights azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, azure-application-insights

I have created Application Insights resource in my azure account. After, I added the instrument key into my windows store app. I have configured Application insights for visual studio 2013. Source code as below,

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("XXXXXX-XXXXXX");
    }
}
```

I want to track the crashes of my application. But crashes didn't get logged inside the portal. Details of the Users, Page Views, Sessions are shown. Apart from adding the instrument key, any other thing should I want to do? Please help.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/

Answer (score 1):

are you simulating an unhandled exception in your application, if so can you please take a look at the output windows in VS we are logging each event we are sending to the backend in the output window or try capture in the events we are sending using fiddler.

also the recommended way to bootstrap the SDK is as follow:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("XXXXXX-XXXXXX");
        InitializeComponent();        
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Meni Zalzman [MSFT]

Answer (score 0):

If you went with the config file approach (`ApplicationInsights.config`), then add the `Add` line to the `TelemetryModules` as shown:

```
<TelemetryModules>
...
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Windows"/>
</TelemetryModules>
```

This will enable automatic logging of crashes.

I don't know if this is the case, but after some testing it appears as if crashes are only logged in Release builds, this might have something to do with the [Debug vs Release mode](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-usage/#debug)

> ### Debug vs Release mode
>
> #### Debug
>
> If you build in debug mode, events are sent as soon as they are generated. If you lose internet connectivity and then exit the app before regaining connectivity, offline telemetry is discarded.
>
> #### Release
>
> If you build in release configuration, events are stored in the device and sent when the application resumes. Data is also sent on the application's first use. If there is no internet connectivity upon startup, previous telemetry as well as telemetry for the current lifecycle is stored and sent on the next resume.